# how to create weight values for those classes with zero samples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, matrix, machine-learning

I have an image which has three values (0,1, and 2) that each of them relates to different objects.
I want to dynamically create a probability matrix (H) like this (reads an image and calculate this for each image):

```
H(i, j) = 0          if i != j
H(i, j) = 1 - f(i)   if i == j (with f(i) = the frequency of class i in array)
```

First I counted pixels with each class:

```
cl0=np.count_nonzero(im == 0)   #0=background class
cl1=np.count_nonzero(im == 1)   #obj1
cl2=np.count_nonzero(im == 2)    #obj2
```

I have set of images that some of them do not have one class so the frequency of that value is zero. For example,`(65228, 308, 0)` for one image. 
Once I want to create inverse class weight by this formula `(total number of sample)/((number of classes)*(number of sample in class i))` to give more probability those classes with less samples.

```
w0=round(sum_/(no_classes*cl0),3)
w1=round(sum_/(no_classes*cl1),3)
w2=round(sum_/(no_classes*cl2),3)
```

I am facing this error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Could someone please guide me how can I tackle with this classes with `zero` samples to tackle imbalance classes? How can I normalize the weights?
Thank u

Comment: You have to decide - what weight you want to assign to zero-count classes.

Comment: @MBo Thanks I just wanted to make sure. I replaced with zero